# Fetching Data from Node/Express endpoint and displaying at React component is not working

Tags: node.js, express, redux

Getting the data stored in the Mongo DB from Node/Express endpoint is working. I've tested it via the Postman and the data are successfully retrieved. But when fetching the data from the React component from the same endpoint, it fails to fetch the data. The Node/Express endpoint is

```
app.get('/api/safety', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const cars = await CarMaker.find({});
            res.status(200).json(cars);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(422).send(error);
        }
    });
```

The Redux action function to fetch data from the above endpoint is

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { FETCH_USER, FETCH_DATA } from './types';

export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/current_user');
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};

export const fetchData = () => async (dispatch) => {
    const res = axios('/api/safety');
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_DATA, payload: res.data });
};
```

The React component, Cars.js, to initiate the action, fetchData, is

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

import CarDetails from './CarDetails';

function Cars({ fetchData, data }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchData]);
    return (
        <div>
            Cars
            <CarDetails data={data} />
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.safety,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Cars);
```

The Cars.js is called from the Header.js by clicking the Car Data button. The Header.js is

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function Header(props) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const renderContent = () => {
        switch (props.auth) {
            case null:
                return;
            case false:
                return (
                    <li>
                        <a href='/auth/google'>Login With Google</a>
                    </li>
                );
            default:
                return [
                    <li key='1'>
                        <a href='/api/logout'>Logout</a>
                    </li>,
                ];
        }
    };

    return (
        <nav>
            <div className='nav-wrapper'>
                <button
                    onClick={() => navigate(props.auth ? '/display' : '/')}
                    className='left brand-logo'
                >
                    Car Data
                </button>
                <ul className='right'>{renderContent()}</ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

function mapStateToProps({ auth }) {
    return { auth };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

The store.js is

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authReducer from './reducers/authReducer';
import safetyReducer from './reducers/safetyReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    safety: safetyReducer,
});

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))
);

export default store;
```

The safetyReducer is

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from '../actions/types';
function safetyReducer(state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATA:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default safetyReducer;
```

The error message on the console is "redux.js:564  Uncaught (in promise) Error: When called with an action of type "fetch_data", the slice reducer for key "safety" returned undefined." while the error message on the screen is "Uncaught runtime error: can not read properties of null (reading 'map').
Please help me locate the issues. I appreciate your help.

Comment: In `/api/safety'` end point. You have forgotten to use `await` and `get` I think. `export const fetchData = () => async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/safety');`

Comment: Thank you for pointing the error. But the same issue persists after adding await.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out the issue. I change the initial state from null to [] and it works. My attempt was inspired by the suggestion from @Joseph D. Thanks, Joseph. And thanks to @Dushan Ranasinghage who pointed out the missing await. The revised safetyReducer function is

```
function safetyReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATA:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```